# how to add a control to other application's UI using vb.net in windows on runtime

Tags: vb.net, windows, user-interface, controls

I want to make an application in vb.net which can put a new control on the running applications in windows in real time.

If anybody has any clue how to do it then please comment. It would be a great help.

Comment: this is what i want to achieve, see the image for a control added to vlc player's UI: [Image](https://imgur.com/Vn14UGJ)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Private Sub Generate_Buttons()
    Dim XPos As Integer = 3
    Dim YPos As Integer = 45

    Dim TempSeries As Integer = Series

    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        newButton = New Button
        newButton.Name = "btnSeriesRow" & i
        newButton.Location = New Point(XPos, YPos)
        newButton.Size = New Drawing.Size(105, 36)
        newButton.Dock = DockStyle.None
        newButton.Text = TempSeries & "00 - " & TempSeries & "99"
        <container>.Controls.Add(newButton)
        AddHandler newButton.Click, AddressOf newButton_click

        YPos += 42
        TempSeries += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

You can create any type of control dynamically using this technique.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but i was asking for how can i add a control like button to an other application's UI which is already running on windows

Comment: I know this isn't VB.NET but it will surely help. its in C#, use Code Converter to use this code. [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80255/Add-Your-Control-On-Top-Another-Application]

Comment: the link you gave, did a great help bro thanx a lot.